# How to use Oracle OLAP cube with Oracle locator?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, olap-cube, oracle-spatial, oracle-olap

I have built an Oracle OLAP cube with 3 dimensions (time, products, location(lat,long)).

So far I can query time and get all the products in all locations. 
What I dont know is...**How can I use Oracle Locator with Oracle OLAP cube so that I can retrieve all the products given a geographical area and time.** I am not sure if I have to edit my location dimension to have Oracle Locator data types, etc..

I'll appreciate if someone could provide me hints or a simple example.

Thanks in advance.